# kasra not displayed on iOS

Tags: ios, uibutton, arabic

When I write arabic text containing the letter kasra (unicode character 0x650, phonetic equivalent i) to a button, the kasra is not displayed. Thus, the word mumkin appears as mumkn. If I inspect the NSString in Xcode, the kasra is present, but the kasra is not displayed in the iPhone simulator or on a real iPad. The other two short vowels (fatha and damma) are displayed correctly.

Comment: It sounds like your font doesn't contain a glyph for that character.  Have you tried another font?

Comment: I am using the system font. Even if you select a different font, iOS 'forgets' the selected font when it joins together the 0x06?? arabic letters to make 0xFE?? letters.

Answer (score 1):

The arabic letter kasra (unicode character 0x650) is missing from all of the built-in IOS7 fonts that i have tried.

The solution was to build a different font into my app- I used AGA-Rasheeq-Bold.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bug.  I just tried it in the storyboard editor and it does not seem to work.  I created a string in the MAC Notes application, copied and pasted.  It displays correctly in the left hand properties panel, but not in the button itself.  Could you provide the exact Unicode string?  You may need to open a bug report with Apple.

I can confirm that it works correctly in a Label field, but not a Button (IOS 6.1 and Xcode 4.6.3)

Try attributed text.  This seems to work around the issue.

Comment: the Unicode is 645 650 64f 645 643 640 650 646. I tried attributed text on the iOS7 iPhone simulator, same problem. I have opened a bug report: $50 to apple for the privilege.